# AOSP 4.3: Emulator not starting after adding a HAL module

Tags: android, c, android-emulator, android-source, hal

I am modifying the AOSP based on Android version 4.3 by adding a new system service and trying to extend the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL).

Implementing the System Service did work and it is usable when a App in the Emulator accesses the Service through Binder. The Service itself tries to load the new HAL module in the cpp part of the service.

The problem is, I cannot add the HAL implementation to the build as the Emulator is then just not starting up. The HAL module itself consists of a simple C-file and the Android.mk

There are no compilation errors and a the .so library is added in the build.
All this based on a [post](http://www.opersys.com/blog/extending-android-hal) Karim Yaghmour for Android 2.3

I created a header file under hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/gen_gpio.h
and placed the implementation shown below into sdk/emulator/gen_gpio

The example provided in the post has the same problem. So I am wondering if there were major changes between Android 2.3 and Android 4.3 and what has to be done differently to add a HAL module to the Emulator (Karim Yaghmour states in his book the same topic that it should still work).

My c-file looks like this.

```
#include <errno.h>

#define  LOG_TAG  "gen_gpio_odroidxu4"
#include <cutils/log.h>
#include <cutils/sockets.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <hardware/gen_gpio.h>

static int gen_gpio_read (char* buffer, int length, int gpio_pin) {
    return 0;

};

static int gen_gpio_write (char* buffer, int length, int gpio_pin) {
    return 0;
};

static int open_gen_gpio(const struct hw_module_t* module, char const*     name, struct hw_device_t** device) {
    struct gen_gpio_device_t *dev = malloc(sizeof(struct gen_gpio_device_t));     //Reserve memory for device struct
    memset(dev, 0, sizeof(*dev)); //Clear memory area

    dev->common.tag = HARDWARE_DEVICE_TAG;
    dev->common.version = 0;
    dev->common.module = (struct hw_module_t*) module;
    dev->read = gen_gpio_read;
    dev->write = gen_gpio_write;

    *device = (struct hw_device_t*) dev;

    return 0;
};

static struct hw_module_methods_t gen_gpio_module_methods = {
    .open = open_gen_gpio
};

const struct hw_module_t HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM = {
    .tag = HARDWARE_MODULE_TAG,
    .version_major = 1,
    .version_minor = 0,
    .id = GEN_GPIO_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID,
    .name = "Generic GPIO HW Module",
    .author = "Christoph Fraedrich",
    .methods = &gen_gpio_module_methods,
};
```

And the make file like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ifneq ($(TARGET_PRODUCT),sim)
# HAL module implemenation, not prelinked and stored in
# hw/<GPS_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID>.<ro.hardware>.so
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_SHARED_LIBRARIES)/hw
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DQEMU_HARDWARE
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils libhardware
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gen_gpio_qemu.c
LOCAL_MODULE := gen_gpio.goldfish
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif
```

Comment: I did, the reason why I did not mention them is that I tested them before without the HAL module (the device then just fails to load) and it worked there. The problem here is, that the emulator does not even start up, only the "Android" splash screen showing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too experimented with adding a [HAL module to *AOSP* 4.2](https://github.com/onikx/aosp-sizeof-hw) based on *Karim Yaghmour's* book and had some troubles. If I remember correctly a mistake in the book was caused by defining `struct hw_module_t` as `const` which resulted in a memory access/write error preventing emulator to boot. Try it as

```
struct hw_module_t HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM
```

Comment: This actually was all that was wrong it seems. Days of searching through code because of a small mistake like this. Thank you so much